# Best way / Standard to size views for Apple iOS

Tags: ios, uikit, frame

Apple has a lot of documentation on best practices and design guidelines such as [this](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/platforms). But they don't really specify the actual standard sizes of particular `UIViews` on iOS, iPadOS, macOS, etc. The closest thing I've seen is that a `UIButton` must have a hit target of at least `44x44px` to be readily selectable.

I am not a big fan of just hardcoding `UIView.frame` values, and much prefer using Auto Layout constraints. But even then, many views need to be explicitly sized and I have not been able to find a reliable, official source for the dimensions of `UIButtons` like a play button, for example. Ideally, I could recreate the native Apple specifications in UIKit, but I am not sure how to go about getting those particular values.

Any help or insight is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS development, many sizes are already predetermined by default, allowing you to leverage those standard sizes. For instance, the default system font has a size of 17px, cell row height is typically 44px, and there are predefined offsets for table view grouped types. Additionally, you can use default fonts, colors, and sizes for section titles in table views. The system also provides safe areas and margins for accommodating different screen sizes.

In most cases, the size of your views will be influenced by the text you use or the constraints defined by your device's screen size. Sometimes, multiple size definitions are required to achieve a desired layout for a single element. Let's consider an example where you want a "play" button positioned at the bottom of a component. Here are a few steps you can follow based on priority:

Start by using text to determine the size of the button.
Consider adding some insets around the text by adding a few pixels on each side.
Take into account that if the text is too small, the button might become too small as well. In such cases, you can restrict the button to have a minimum size, ensuring it remains visible.
Remember to ensure that the button fits on screens of various sizes by constraining it within the screen borders. This way, it won't get cut off on smaller screens.
Address the issue of the button looking too small on larger screens, such as iPads, by defining a maximum button size. This ensures that the button maintains an appropriate visual proportion.
By setting these priorities and using the system font, your button will automatically resize based on the accessibility settings defined by the user's system preferences on their phone.

In my experience, few apps include features such as accessibility and content resizing based on it. Additionally, most apps do not use default sizes extensively. For example, when you navigate to the "App Store," you'll notice larger cells compared to those in "Settings," which typically have a height of 44px. The current version of the App Store showcases small buttons, as depicted in the image below:

[image]

However, if you interact with those "GET" buttons, you'll realize that they can be pressed well outside their visual boundaries. The research on 44x44px size is more about determining the hit area for your components rather than focusing solely on the visual size of the elements.

Your challenge can be divided into two aspects: the visual representation size and the usable area for interaction with the components. Apple recommends a minimum press area of 44x44px for any component. Ideally, you should strive to expand the interactive area as much as possible, allowing users to tap on cells or sections comfortably.

Regarding the visual aspect, default text sizes and provided glyphs offer a good starting point. Combined with a touch of design finesse, these defaults should suffice for most applications. If you choose to work with SwiftUI, you'll find that it sets up more defaults, such as spacing in stack views and default paddings.

Remember to strike a balance between adhering to Apple's standards and creating visually appealing and user-friendly app experiences. While guidelines and best practices are valuable, it's essential to consider your app's unique requirements and design preferences.